# В чем отличие вывода у программ?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Была дана легкая задачка: "Вам даётся натуральное число N. Напишите программу, которая выведет в порядке возрастания все натуральные числа от 1 до N, которые являются точными квадратами."

Написал я две программы, выдают одно и то же, но при проверке программы сайтом, одна из них не проходит тесты.

Я хотел бы узнать, чем отличаются выводы данных программ? Может я что-то не догоняю

```
N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    if i**0.5 == round(i**0.5):
        if i != 0:
            print(i)
```

и

```
n = int(input())
i = 1
while i ** 2 <= n:
    print(i ** 2)
    i += 1
```

Comment: а, это я случайно изменил первую переменную, когда вставлял код на сайт, уже поменял обратно

Comment: Вывод разный. Смотрите внимательнее. Введите число, которое является квадратом.

Comment: Все, понял свою ошибку с range, спасибо